# How do you create a LinkedList which contains loops?

Tags: python, oop, object, pointers, linked-list

I'm trying to come up with a test case for the solution given by hackerrank for detecting cycles in a linkedlist with python. The solution given by hackerrank is:

```
class Node(object):
def __init__(self, data = None, next_node = None):
    self.data = data
    self.next = next_node

def has_cycle(head):
    fast = head;

    while(fast != None and fast.next != None):
        fast = fast.next.next;
        head = head.next;

        if(head == fast):
            return True;

    return False;
```

So I created what I thought was the following LinkedList

```
8 -> 7 -> 6 -> 5 -> 4 -> 3
     ^                   |
     |                   V
     1 <-----------------2
```

Using this code:

```
Node_1 = Node(1)
Node_2 = Node(2, Node_1)
Node_3 = Node(3, Node_2)
Node_4 = Node(4, Node_3)
Node_5 = Node(5, Node_4)
Node_6 = Node(6, Node_5)
Node_7 = Node(7, Node_6)
Node_8 = Node(8, Node_7)
Node_1 = Node(1, Node_7)
```

But the results weren't what I expected:

```
print(has_cycle(Node_8))  # returns False
print(Node_2.next.next)  # returns None 
print(Node_1.next.data)  # returns 7
```

This would work in C++, so it makes me think the problem is that I'm passing copies of objects rather than their pointers. If that's the case could someone point me to some material to learn about those sorts of concepts, please?

Also, how would I create the above mentioned test case?

Thanks!

Comment: looking at your loop thing, shouldn't the next node for `Node_1` be node 7?

Comment: You are creating two nodes nodes called `Node_1`.

Comment: Also, slap whoever put all the `;` in that solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line:

```
Node_1 = Node(1, Node_7)
```

is creating a *new* node, it's not modifying the original `Node_1` that's linked from `Node_2`. The lists you've created look like:

```
8 -> 7 -> 6 -> 5 -> 4 -> 3 -> 2 -> 1
     ^
1 ---|
```

To create a cycle, you need a way to modify the `next` link of an existing node. Add this method to the `Node` class:

```
def set_next(self, next_node = None):
    self.next = next_node
```

Then replace the last line with:

```
Node_1.set_next(Node_7)
```

Comment: Where does the `set_next` method come from?

Comment: You need to add it to the `Node` class.

Comment: couldn't you also just define node 1 last?

Comment: @SuperStew Then what will you use in `Node_2`?

Comment: oh yea. makes sense